# Python authorize imgur OAuth2.0 authentication to fetch subreddit gallery

Tags: python, api, authentication, imgur

So I'm trying to access the imgur API for the list of images in a certain reddit subgallery. This is what I've tried so far:

```
>>> header = {'client_id': 'thisismyclientid', 'response_type': 'pin'}
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize', headers=header, verify=False)
>>> r.text
u'{"data":{"error":"client_id and response_type are required","request":"\\/oauth2\\/authorize","parameters":"","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":400}'
```

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, is this not the correct way to pass my client_id and response type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick look at the documentation reveals:

```
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=REQUESTED_RESPONSE_TYPE&state=APPLICATION_STATE
```

Those are get parameters, not headers. So you have to pass the dictionary as `params` instead of `headers`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't realize this :| Million thanks!

Comment: No problem. I would advise *against* using `verify=False` (you have to, if you are using python 2, as it won't work otherwise). If you have python3.2 try removing `verify=False`